# Is there a program to calculate fibonacci charts and their continuations?

Tags: charts, trendlines

I'd need a program able to take data and plot a trend graph, and it should be able to continue it to see the future trend. I've found some commercial programs but none work. Is there a free one?
I once saw some graphs with grey background and blue dots. What's the program that makes those?

Comment: Are you looking for Excel Trendline like behaviour or something different?

Comment: I think the exact name is Fibonacci Retracements. Not sure if that feature exists in excel. Does it?

Comment: Well...if you know the formula of the trend, you could use any plotting application (GNUPlot, wolframalpha.com etc.)...do you know the formula?

Comment: no, that's the problem. The only data is the actual coordinates for the graph. and yes i'd have to find the formula.

Comment: It's mathematically impossible to determine a trend from a finite number of data points without making some sort of assumption about the form of the trend. I'm not familiar with Fibonacci retracements specifically, but I looked up some material online and I don't see how you'd be able to extrapolate a trend based on that method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Excel for that - check this tutorial: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/spreadsheetlessons/qt/Fibonacci_Numbe.htm

Comment: Nope, that's a different thing.
http://tf2stats.net/wrenches contains the list. Of that list, I'd want to graph the trend of a the crafts value or seconds.